# Styling for checked checkboxes in <Datagrid>

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-admin

I am trying to add some custom theming to a React Admin site, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to style the checked state of the bulk action select checkboxes in a list view. I can set generic checkbox styles using `withStyles` and passing `checkbox` into the classes object, but I can't seem to pass in custom `checked` styles that way. Is there any way to do this short of writing my own version of Datagrid? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not currently but it should be fairly easy to implement on our side. Can you open a feature request issue on https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin?